# Creating one long/big "if" out of individual "if's"

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, gregorian-calendar

I have been given a task for college and it is to create a program where the user will input the date and the program will return a numerical value which corresponds with the day of that specific date.

3 things must be taken into consideration:

- Before the 3rd of September 1752 there is an equation that is used to generate a numerical value. However....
- After the 13th of September 1752 the calendar was changed to more accurately represent the days in the year and therefore a different equation is used to represent these dates.
- Lastly, between the 3rd and the 13th of September 1752 the program should return that these dates did not exist at all since the change in calendar skipped the days in between.

I have an if statement that I want to be one big condition instead of separate ones:

```
if (yyyy <= 1752 && mm <= 9 && dd < 3)
```

But the problem is if I choose a date that is on the **year 1752**, that is on or before **the 9th month**, and has a day that is **higher than 3**, an answer will not be returned. Therefore (dd/mm/yyyy) >3/January-August/1752 will not return an answer.

The rest of the code if anyone wants to mess around with it/test something:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Please enter your desired date(dd/mm/yyyy): ");    
    String date = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    int d1 = (date.charAt(0)-48)*10;
    int d2 = date.charAt(1)-48;
    int dd = d1+d2;
    int m1 = (date.charAt(3)-48)*10;
    int m2 = date.charAt(4)-48;
    int mm = m1+m2;
    int y1 = (date.charAt(6)-48)*1000;
    int y2 = (date.charAt(7)-48)*100;
    int y3 = (date.charAt(8)-48)*10;
    int y4 = date.charAt(9)-48;
    int yyyy = y1+y2+y3+y4;  

    if (dd <= 13 && dd >= 3 && mm == 9 && yyyy == 1752){
        System.out.println("This date never occured.");

    } if (dd > 13 && mm >= 9 && yyyy >= 1752 || yyyy>1752){
       {

            while(true){
                if (dd > 31){
                    System.out.println("This is not a valid day.");
                    dd = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
                }
                if (mm > 12){
                    System.out.println("This is not a valid month.");
                    mm = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
                }
                if (mm == 1){
                    mm = 13;
                }
                if (mm== 2){
                    mm = 14;
                }
                else{
                    int answer;
                    answer = (dd +((26*(mm+1))/10)+yyyy+(yyyy/4)+6*(yyyy/100)+(yyyy/400))%7;
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    System.out.println("The day was/is: "+answer);
                    System.out.println("Sa: 0, Su: 1, M: 2, Tu: 3, W: 4, Th: 5, F: 6");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ((yyyy <= 1752 && mm <= 9 && dd < 3) || yyyy < 1752){
        {

            while(true){
                if (dd > 31){
                    System.out.println("This is not a valid day.");
                    dd = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
                }
                if (mm > 12){
                    System.out.println("This is not a valid month.");
                    mm = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
                }
                if (mm == 1){
                    mm = 13;
                }
                if (mm== 2){
                    mm = 14;
                }
                else{
                    int answer;
                    answer = (dd+(26*(mm+1)/10)+yyyy+(yyyy/4)+5)%7;
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    System.out.println("The day was/is: "+answer);
                    System.out.println("Sa: 0, Su: 1, M: 2, Tu: 3, W: 4, Th: 5, F: 6");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated :3 thank you!

Comment: Tag language! it affects syntax coloring and helps people to find the question. Also: check your indentation, and make sure it is consistent and readable code.

Comment: You also have what looks like an extra `{` in there... (and maybe some extra `}` too)

Comment: In the real world the programmer is often expected to check the sanity of the problem statement, as well as implement a solution to the stated program. You might want to check the problem statement to see if it recognizes that the Julian/Gregorian switch happened on different dates in different countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If(yyyy <= 1752)
{
    If(yyyy==1752)
    {
        If(mm<=09)
        {
            If(mm==09)
            {
                If(dd >3 && dd<13)
                     Print("Date never occurred.");
                Else if(dd<3)
                    Equation1(date);
                Else 
                    Equation2(date);
            }
            Else
                Equation1(date);
        }
        else
        {
            Equation2(date);
        }
    }
    else
        Equation1(date);
}
Else
{
  Equation2(date);
}
```

I tried a pseudocode, it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 3 branches, for the first one, it would be something like this:

```
Before the 3rd of September 1752 there is an equation that is used to generate a numerical value. 

if (yyyy < 1752 ||           // year is before 1752, so it obviously matches
   (yyyy == 1752 &&          // year is 1752, but we have to determine month
        (mm < 9              // month is before sept
        || (mm == 9 && dd < 3)  // month is sept, but before the 3rd.
        )
   )
   ){
}
```

Use the same kind of logic for the second case, and then an ELSE statement would catch everything else in the third case.

Note: I have not tested this, and it could be that the mm or dd are at an offset by 1 according to your code.